# VBA to copy data from cell above if blank and stop when next data, then repeat

Tags: vba

I've been going through tutorials for the past two days to start my journey in VBA, and need some help for an immediate problem. I currently receive a report from an ACCESS database that I don't have access to, and need to get the data filled correctly so that I can then start using vlookups etc and (hopefully) create some automated timesheet population and calculations. The format of the report does not change, but the amount of data in it will alter based on the amount of users clocking in and out every day. I've attached an image showing the needs that I have; I've tried to do some VBA myself but I'm just to new at it to get anywhere, except for confused.

Can anyone help me? 
VBA Sheet example
[image]

Comment: Usually we are not helping people that don't show efforts and since you have not posted any code no one has helped you even though the code is very simple to do. This time I wrote the code for you but please study this page which is the guideline to ask a good question:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy this code in a module and run it while the sheet is active or change the code to exactly reference the sheet where there is: `set WS=...`
The logic behind the code is simple, if the dates column is filled and the column before that is blank, then copy the values from top to bottom:

```
Sub FillBelowRows()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    lRow = WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 3 To lRow
        If WS.Range("I" & i) <> "" And WS.Range("H" & i) = "" Then
            WS.Range("E" & i & ":H" & i).Value = WS.Range("E" & i - 1 & ":H" & i - 1).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested the code and it works. Once the code works on your side you need to give feedback by clicking the checkmark on the upper left. That will give you 2 points and me 10 points. You will need to collect points to have privileges such as making comments etc. Welcome to StackOverflow and VBA land!

Comment: Done and done, thanks for the warm and helpful welcome :)

Comment: also you can upvote and downvote answers or even questions with those gray triangles. If someone posted an answer that was really helpful you can award him by the upvote, but you can only choose one answer is the APPROVED answer, so this mechanism helps the users to quickly see which question or answer was a more useful post or a bad post. for example posts with too many downvotes will be deleted eventually to keep the forum clean

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by recording a macro and then applying it across multiple sheets with a button. Macro function recorded is as follows:

```
Select columns E:H
F5
Special
Select blank 
= and then up one cell using the arrow key 
ctrl + enter
```

Reading the code you posted has helped me to look at the problem in an entirely new way, thank you so much for the help. As you can maybe tell by my workaround, I'm still new to VBA, but am keen to learn. Thanks again!

Comment: recording macro is good to know what functions excel uses, but it is totally a different method. In good VBA codes we do NOT use `select` to do things, while the recorded code is actually like a log that is created and it is the interaction of the user with the interface so looking at the recorded code is good to start, but do NOT think that recorded code is what exactly you need to do things with VBA